# Katalon Studio deleting groovy code from script when switching to manual or recording

Tags: katalon-studio

Did anybody see this as well, or am I doing something wrong?

I am working on a test case with Katalon Studio, in script mode. I have some Groovy script in it, (in particular a class definition, see start of code below). When I switch mode to work in manual or record mode, and then back to script mode, the groovy code (the class declaration in the example below) has disappeared...

Not very practical! Anything that should be done to avoid this?
Many thanks!
E.

Code example:

```
//Katalon Imports here

class Product {
    String nozo
    String price_string
    Number qty = 1
    Number price_ht = 0
    Number price_ttc = 0

    Product(String nozo, String price_string, Number qty = 1) {
        this.nozo = nozo
        this.price_string = price_string
        def get_price = (this.price_string =~/(\d+)\s(\d+\.\d{2})/)
        if(get_price) {
            this.price_ttc = get_price[1] + get_price[2]
        }
        else this.price_ttc = 0
        this.price_ht = this.price_ttc / 1.2
    }

    def get_price_order_line_ht() {
        return this.price_ht * this.qty
    }
}

// Intialisation of test data
Number qty_pdt1 = 2

'Open home page'
WebUI.openBrowser('http://localhost:8080/')

'Navigate to subrange'
WebUI.doubleClick(findTestObject('Object Repository/vb_desktop/home_page_desktop_fr/a_Lampadaire'))
// Etc...
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Katalon v5.8.6. Which version are you using?

Comment: 5.8.6 as well. Don't know what's happening to me, but good to know that the problem is with me. Will try to keep looking for an explanation. Many thanks!

Comment: OK, so it seems to me that Katalon in 'manual' mode only accepts Keywords, from the imported or custom packages. Any Groovy (and maybe Java) code entered in script mode is executed perfectly, but switching to and making any modification in Manual mode means that the Groovy code is erased from the Script.

Comment: OK, so it seems to me that Katalon in 'manual' mode only accepts Keywords, from the imported or custom packages. Any Groovy (and maybe Java) code entered in script mode is executed perfectly, but switching to and making any modification in Manual mode means that the Groovy code is erased from the Script.

The way may be to create a custom keyword with the code. I see how that can work for a method. Not clear on how to declare a Groovy class in there.

E.

Comment: You can follow the short tutorial [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/how-to-use-custom-keyword-in-groovy-class.html).

Comment: Thanks, will look at it! E.